# Selecting the lowest/highest with find_one in Pymongo

Tags: pymongo

I can do

```
db.find({'node_type': {'$regex':'^meta-'}}).sort("id", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

I assume `find` returns a lazy iterator and `sort` modifies it in-place, and no data is fetched unless the iterator is used.

But I want to use `find_one` with sort parameters; in this case, fetch the document with the highest ID. What's the correct usage for this need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `find_one` with sorting, because `find_one` returns document directly (or None). So you can use `find` with `sort` or you can use the aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {node_type: {$regex: '^meta-'}}},
    {$sort: {id: -1}},
    {$limit: 1}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `.limit(1)`

```
db.find({'node_type': {'$regex':'^meta-'}}).limit(1).sort("_id", -1)
```

or

```
db.find({'node_type': {'$regex':'^meta-'}}, limit=1).sort("_id", -1)
```